# Is this result for the leading digits of $2^{2^{2^{32}}}$ accurate?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, digits

I have used Mathematica to compute the leading digits of very large powers. My largest calculation was to find the first digits of $2^{2^{2^{32}}}$, whose number of digits is itself a number of over a billion digits, using the following code:

```
nbrdgt = 100; f[base_, exp_] := 
RealDigits[ 10^FractionalPart[ 
N[ exp*Log10[ base], nbrdgt + Floor[Log10[ exp]] + 2]], 10, 
nbrdgt][[1]]; f[2, 2^2^32]
```

This is the code [I found on the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A241291), which has the first digits of all of the numbers $n^{n^{n^n}}$ from n=3 to 9. The code calculates the decimal logarithm of the base multiplied by the exponent, accurate to the necessary amount of digits to calculate the digits just after the decimal point, with enough digits after the decimal point to calculate the first `nbrdgt` digits, and then takes 10 to the power of the fractional part.

After 30 hours of running time (the computation also took around 4 or 5 gigabytes of RAM), I obtained the result

[3, 1, 5, 9, 2, 1, 2, 6, 9, 3, 3, 7, 2, 3, 3, 8, 4, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 8, 4, 8, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 6, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 8, 8, 3, 6, 5, 9, 1, 1, 6, 5, 0, 3, 2, 4, 9, 6, 7, 1, 1, 9, 1, 7, 0, 6, 8, 9, 1, 8, 3, 2, 9, 9, 3, 6, 7, 0, 9, 8, 4, 1, 2, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 0, 4, 2, 8, 0, 3, 9, 4]

which suggests that $2^{2^{2^{32}}} = 3159212693.........1317364736$ with about $9.3418 \times 10^{1,292,913,985}$ digits.

Is Mathematica actually reliable to 1.293 billion digits? In other words, is the result above correct? Or was there a roundoff error or other issue? The code is known to be reliable to at least 1,000,000 digits (as the result I obtained for $2^{4^{6^8}}$'s first digits using the same code has been confirmed to be correct, and that number has a 1,011,230-digit number of digits).

Comment: Your statement that: "The code is known to be reliable to at least 1,000,000 digits (as the result I obtained for 2468's first digits using the same code has been confirmed to be correct, and that number has a 1,011,230-digit number of digits)." is logically incorrect. Yes, it gave you the correct answer in this instance. Will it do so for any equivalent calculation of 1,000,000 digits? My guess is that if you can ***prove*** that (from your knowledge of Mathematica internals), then you will be able to repeat the calculation (and verification) for 1,000,000,000 digits!

Comment: You mention the fact that you found the code on OEIS. Please tell us the OEIS sequence number or, more simply, put a link to it on your mention of OEIS.

Comment: It can be found in A241291, A241292, A241293, A241294, A241295, A241296, A241297, A241298, and A243913.

Comment: @AllamA. OEIS has Maple and Mathematica code. So?